# Confused by Bootstrap 4 .list-inline class vs. .list-inline-item class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm using `Bootstrap 4` inside Wordpress. For some reason, I cannot get lists items to display inline (horizontally) using only the class `.list-inline` on the list, like this:

```
<ul id="dances" class="list-unstyled list-inline">
    <li>Plena</li>
    <li>Danza</li>
    <li>Bomba</li>
</ul>
```

It only works if I put the class `.list-inline-item` on the actual list items individually, like this below, which seems superfluous:

```
<ul id="animals" class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="list-inline-item">Giraffes</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Elephants</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Donkeys</li>
</ul>
```

I'm new to Bootstrap, and I can't recall where I found the class `.list-inline-item`, because I can't find it in the Bootstrap 4 class list anywhere. For example on this [cheatsheet](https://jsfiddle.net/Katrina_B/8L5hzsxp/).

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Katrina_B/8L5hzsxp/) so you can better see it in action.

(Please view the fiddle in a wide browser.)

Notice how the "`Animals`" list in the yellow displays horizontally, but the "`Dances`" in the pink do not. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 4**

To display inline list : http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/#inline

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Phasellus iaculis</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Nulla volutpat</li>
</ul>
```

As mentioned here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#inline, you'll have to use `display: inline-block;` to make the list inline. ([Bootstrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#inline) for `list-inline` is using `type.less` which provides each `li` element `display: inline-block;`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't understand why we need two rules, one for the UL and then one for each list item? Isn't that superfluous? 

I also don't quite get why we need to add certain self-explanatory rules to predefined Bootstrap classes ourselves, when I assumed they would be built in. Obviously I am wrong, and have a lot to learn, but as asked above to another responder, Why is it we have to manually add rules for .list-inline class when we don't have to do the same for the class .list-unstyled, for example?

Comment: @user2998925, I understand, but it if we have `list-inline` behaves as you want it to, then if we need 3 items in a list out of which 2 must be in a single and third should not, we won't be able to do it. It's better to provide what style we want on an element rather than the negation of it. So it is basically typography and you can see the Bootstrap code : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_type.scss#L88, they have provided same styling to `list-unstyled` and `list-inline`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me understand. I'm still a bit confused, but will spend some time to try and understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Besides of how Bootstrap works, if you don't want to put list-inline-item individually on each item, you can define the parent style to act as you want:

```css
.list-inline{text-align:center}
.list-inline li{display:inline-block;margin:5px;}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh! Am i supposed to add the CSS rules to the .list-inline li myself in my style sheet? I already knew how to use CSS rules to make the lists display inline, but I thought Bootstrap classes were "built in" so to speak, and already had rules attached to them. When I add the class .list-unstyled to a list, i don't have to then go and add list-style-type:none to that class in my stylesheet—it happens automatically because .list-unstyled is a Bootstrap class.

Why does one rule work one way when another works differently?